# Help with PInvoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I got the next c function:

```
long _stdcall _MakePipeString(char *szOut, long nOutChars, const char *szXmlFile, long nOptions);
```

And I try to use pInvioke like this:

```
[DllImport("diXo10.dll")]
public static extern long _MakePipeString(out StringBuilder szOut, out long nOutChars, string szXmlFile, long nOptions);
```

But i get null in the ouput variable szOut.

Am I doing wrong?

Please help.

Comment: i think you have a variable problem, szOut shouldn't be __char **szOut__ ?

Comment: Depends who is going to provide the buffer space. But you're right, usually, when the caller provides the buffer, a max length is also passed in. However, the nOutChars is also by value and not by reference, so that it's strange anyways.

Answer (score 1):

In additions to what others have said, change the longs to ints on the C# side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
[DllImport("diXo10.dll")]
public static extern long _MakePipeString([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out String szOut, out long nOutChars, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szXmlFile, long nOptions);
```

Note that you may also have to specify whether you expect ANSI or Unicode(UTF16) characters, for instance by using LPTStr/LPWStr instead of LPStr or on the [DllImport attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b93s42f.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

try without the `out` parameter.

see [here](http://michaelellerbeck.com/2009/02/11/using-pinvoke-with-char/).